# Ошибка установки Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Не могу установить Visual Studio 2013 на свой компьютер...

Система: Windows 8.1

Вот какую ошибку выдает:

[image]

Пробовал с правами Админа, отключал антивирус(ESET Smart Security), не помогло...

Прикрепляю логи:

```
    [0938:04B0][2014-12-21T14:39:37]i000: MUX:  Free Disk Space before install:  SystemDrive C:\ 13549228032 bytes  AppDrive C:\ 13549228032 bytes
[1338:11F8][2014-12-21T14:39:37]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[1338:11F8][2014-12-21T14:39:37]i361: Created a system restore point.
[1338:11F8][2014-12-21T14:39:37]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{c96467b4-e480-4218-8fde-db83bf9d47d1}, options: 0x4, disable resume: No
[1338:11F8][2014-12-21T14:39:37]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {c96467b4-e480-4218-8fde-db83bf9d47d1}, version: 12.0.31101.0
[1338:11F8][2014-12-21T14:39:37]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{c96467b4-e480-4218-8fde-db83bf9d47d1}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[1338:11F8][2014-12-21T14:39:37]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to write run key value.
[1338:11F8][2014-12-21T14:39:37]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to update resume mode.
[1338:11F8][2014-12-21T14:39:37]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to begin registration session.
[0938:04B0][2014-12-21T14:39:37]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to begin registration session in per-machine process.
[0938:04B0][2014-12-21T14:39:37]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to register bundle.
[0938:04B0][2014-12-21T14:39:37]i000: MUX:  Apply Complete: Disk Space Used in bytes for Installation:  MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 1265664  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 1265664
[0938:04B0][2014-12-21T14:39:37]i000: MUX:  Free Disk Space after install:  SystemDrive C:\ 13547962368 bytes  AppDrive C:\ 13547962368 bytes
[0938:04B0][2014-12-21T14:39:37]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147024891 (0x80070005), Error Message=, Result Detail=, Vital=True, Package Action=Install, Package Id=Apply Failure
[0938:04B0][2014-12-21T14:39:37]i000: MUX:  Go to Finished page.
[0938:04B0][2014-12-21T14:39:37]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070005, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заблокирован ключ реестра, скорее антивирус хоть и отключен, но не совсем...

Comment: Я даже удалял антивирус, не помогло. Ладно, проблему решил переустановкой винды, все равно пора была переустанавливать...